# Google Storage Rsync Exclusion

Tags: python, regex, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the gcloud rsync utility to sync only files that match a certain date string, ex: 14-Sep-2015

The file structure is as follows: `bucket/123/CODE_14-Sep-2015.txt`

So when I rsync I only want to sync files matching a certain date. This is because we occasionally prune old files from the local system and don't want to keep rsyncing those old files.

Here's what I'm attempting:

`gsutil -m rsync -n -x '[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+_((?!15-Aug-2015).*)' -r gs://bucket folder;`

When I tested the regex in a test environment it seems to work fine, but it's still pulling other files that do not match that date.

Any idea why this is not working as expected? Is there a better way to achieve this than rsync?

Comment: Close? Do python regular expressions not fall under the scope of stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My regexp is correct, but did not work on my version of python/gsutil for some reason. I've found an easier way to achieve the desired result though.

Simply using copy:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://bucket_name/*/*15-Sep-2015.txt destination_folder
```

It's just using wildcards, no regexp required.

#### Note: cp does not seem to be copying the directory structure like rsync, for example...

gs://bucket/123/file.txt gets copied to /destination_folder/file.txt instead of /destination_folder/123/file.txt

#### UPDATE:

So the copy functionality works as documented and unfortunately seems a bit counter intuitive to me, but I found the working solution using rsync.

I had an extra directory layer that I was not matching so it broke my entire regexp. So it's worth noting that you must match the entire path after the bucket name for the regexp to work.

### Working Answer:

```
gsutil -m rsync -n -x '[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+_((?!15-Aug-2015).*)' -r gs://bucket/subfolder folder;
```

Answer (score 2):

With `(?!15-Aug-2015)` regex will match every date, excluding 15-Aug-2015. If you want to match files with particular date, it would be better to use positive lookahead, like:

```
[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+_((?=14-Sep-2015)).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF0zV4/2)

But if it is about exclusion, maybe you should add desired format after `(?!15-Aug-2015)`, without it it will match every file which match for `[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+_` which is not followed by excluded part ([demo for invalid match examples](https://regex101.com/r/uZ8mA2/1)). To avoid that try:

```
[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+_((?!15-Sep-2015))\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{4}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF0zV4/4)

Comment: I want it to match everything except what's in the regexp. Because the regexp is for an exclusion group. Anything it matches gets excluded from the sync.

Comment: @EricUldall I updated answer, however if it is not what you meant, please add an example of file name which your regex match, but you don't want it to match?

Comment: Unfortunately I've found my regexp is correct, but it's not working on my system correctly. It was tested on another gsutil install and worked fine. I'm not sure why this is the case, perhaps some difference in my version of python. Fortunately there's an easier way to do this using the cp command.